# How to open specific third party activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Ok I want to open a specific `Activity` from a app, not my app. Let's say that I want to open this package `com.test.app` and inside that package `TestActivity`. How can I do this?

I have tried like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(pack, activity);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

Intent i = new Intent(pack+activity);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(pack, "."+activity);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

Intent i = new Intent(pack+"."+activity);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```

With all of them I'm having this error:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {PACKAGE/ACTIVITY}; have your declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

NOTE: I do have the app installed with package `com.test.app` and with an activity `TestActivity`. So how could this be done?

Comment: try this i.setClassName("com.test.app", "com.test.app.TestActivity");

Comment: @hemanthkumar That's not working as I have set it before and gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must make sure that the target activity is exported. It must be exported explicitly with android:export="true", or implicitly, with an intent-filter. You can't send an Intent to any random Activity of any app.

Answer (score 0):

do u try below code?

```
Intent i = new Intent();// if TestActivity has an action. please add by yourself
i.setClassName("com.test.app", "com.test.app.TestActivity");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);// maybe no use here
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: That's not working as I have set it before and gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

check the 3rd party application is installed in your device or emulator, then only it will gives the proper result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have not declared the new java class in manifest file. If not then open your manifest file, open ANdroidmanifest.xml and inside the  tag below  tag write this

Comment: <activity android:name=".YOUR_NEW_JAVA_CLASS_NAME"></activity>

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?